# How to define restfull routes to seperate 2 categories of 1 class with Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I already worked on this topic, but only found a partial solution. Here is better explained the problem:

I manage 2 categories of Business Objects:

1. Defined business objects, which can be considered as templates (there is a flag is_template=true)
2. Used business objects, which are copies of the previous ones, implemented, with small differences

I have 3 expectations about the routing:

1. Rely on helpers such as used_business_objects_path or new_defined_business_object_path
2. Display user friendly URLs, such as /used_metadata/new (metatada is the name asked by my customer to display instead of Business Object)
3. Propagate a type variable to be used by the controller

I'd like to build a resourceful route for those, including a parameter for the controller to which type of object he should select:

```
  # GET /business_objects
  # GET /business_objects.json
  def index
    if params[:type] == 'defined'
      @business_objects = BusinessObject.joins(translated_objects).pgnd(current_playground).defined.visible.search(params[:criteria]).
      select(index_fields).order(order_by).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => paginate_lines)
    else
      @business_objects = BusinessObject.joins(translated_objects).pgnd(current_playground).used.visible.search(params[:criteria]).
        select(index_fields).order(order_by).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => paginate_lines)
    end
```

I implemented a scoped route, based on a suggestion by [nick garrett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13036231/nick-garrett):

```
  scope :type, constraints: { :type => /(defined|used)/ } do
    resources :business_objects, :path => "#{:type}_metadata"  do
      resources :skills                   
      resources :skills_imports, :only=>[:new, :create]
      resources :scopes
      member do
        post :new_version
        post :make_current
        post :finalise
        post :activate
        post :open_cart     # Declares that the current business object collects skills as a cart
        post :close_cart    # Unsets the current business as cart
        get  :derive
      end
      collection do
        get :index_all
      end
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately, this generates a URL as /type/type_metadata?type=used and helpers do not seem to consider type as a parameter.

After reading the Rails routing guide, I am not sure that what I try to achieve is possible. Can you help find a solution for this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do here correctly you can it with [routing concerns](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns):

```
# have absolutely no clue what to name this
concerns :business_object do
  resources :skills                   
  resources :skills_imports, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :scopes
  member do
    post :new_version
    post :make_current
    post :finalise
    post :activate
    post :open_cart     # Declares that the current business object collects skills as a cart
    post :close_cart    # Unsets the current business as cart
    get  :derive
  end
  collection do
    get :index_all
  end
end

resources :used_business_objects, concerns: :business_object 
resources :defined_business_objects, concerns: :business_object
```

I wouldn't bother with tinkering around with that type parameter. Just use inheritance and setup two classes of controller.